# what is the normal size for a sencha touch app?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I built a sencha app using sencha Cmd, the app has the size of 17.4mb.
Is this the normal size for a web app? How can I reduce it?

Comment: It's not. Did it get minified? Can you provide listing with sizes for different files?

Comment: Sencha cmd generated touch folder with 16.1mb, in it there are resources and src folders with 4.92mb and 3.56mb, the files sencha-touch-all and sencha-touch-all-debug are 3.29mb each. Where can I get the minified version?

Comment: Are you building production or test code?

Comment: I was using test build, now with production build the size is 990kb, do you think 990kb is a good size?

Comment: Yeap. I just posted the answer. 1M is totally normal size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually size of minified sencha file would be around 1M. And your application file (depend of course on the size of application) would be around same size 0.5-1.5M too.

Comment: There are more things to implement and I'll build it again and check the size, but that's I wanted know. Thank you!